# How to unlist to a dataframe while maintaining nested lists as columns

Tags: r, json, list, shiny

I have a list called "merged". Within each object in the list there are nested lists for "input", "output", and "session". Ultimately I would like to unlist all this into a dataframe that is easy to work. This data comes from shiny app logs and I would like to be able to select and filter variables to see how users are interacting with the app. I am new to lists and need help getting this data into a format I can work.

Head dput

```
data <- list(list(inputs = structure(list(name = c(".shinymanager_logout", 
"cap_table_search", "cap_table_rows_all", "cap_table_state", 
"site_map_center", "cap_table_state", "cap_table_cells_selected", 
"cap_table_cell_clicked", "cap_table_rows_selected", "region_map", 
"site_map_center", "site_map_zoom", "site_map_bounds", "site_map_bounds", 
"cap_table_columns_selected", "site_map_zoom", "site_map", "cap_table_rows_current"
), timestamp = c("2023-05-04 08:29:48.355-0700", "2023-05-04 08:29:39.094-0700", 
"2023-05-04 08:29:39.093-0700", "2023-05-04 08:29:39.334-0700", 
"2023-05-04 08:29:44.125-0700", "2023-05-04 08:29:39.093-0700", 
"2023-05-04 08:29:39.090-0700", "2023-05-04 08:29:39.094-0700", 
"2023-05-04 08:29:39.090-0700", "2023-05-04 08:29:39.152-0700", 
"2023-05-04 08:29:44.049-0700", "2023-05-04 08:29:44.125-0700", 
"2023-05-04 08:29:44.125-0700", "2023-05-04 08:29:44.049-0700", 
"2023-05-04 08:29:39.090-0700", "2023-05-04 08:29:44.049-0700", 
"2023-05-04 08:29:40.663-0700", "2023-05-04 08:29:39.092-0700"
), value = list(1L, "", list(), list(time = 1683214179333, start = 0L, 
    length = 10L, order = list(), search = list(search = "", 
        smart = TRUE, regex = FALSE, caseInsensitive = TRUE), 
    columns = structure(list(visible = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), search = structure(list(
        search = c("", "", ""), smart = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), 
        regex = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), caseInsensitive = c(TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    3L))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 3L))), list(
    lng = -82.6248, lat = 12.7017), structure(list(), names = character(0)), 
    list(), structure(list(), names = character(0)), list(), 
    c("altos_de_campana", "boraceia", "california", "caribbean", 
    "chiriqui", "el_cope", "el_valle", "fortuna", "gamboa", "louisiana", 
    "new_mexico", "pennsylvania", "santa_fe", "santa_virginia", 
    "tennessee", "vermont"), list(lng = -82.6248, lat = 12.7017), 
    3L, list(north = 49.2678, east = 5.2734, south = -29.6881, 
        west = -170.5078), list(north = 49.2678, east = 5.2734, 
        south = -29.6881, west = -170.5078), list(), 3L, c("10008", 
    "10032", "10037", "10055", "10069", "10081", "10090", "10091", 
    "10095", "10100", "10101", "10102", "10103", "10109", "10110", 
    "10111", "10114", "10196", "10197", "10198", "10199", "10206", 
    "10218", "10220", "10223", "10225", "10227", "10228", "10263", 
    "10276", "10277", "10284", "10285", "10314", "10315", "10316", 
    "10319", "10418", "10420", "10421", "10422", "10423", "10461", 
    "10473", "10474", "10475", "10476", "10477", "10486", "10487", 
    "10488", "10489", "10490", "10511", "10533", "10570", "10571", 
    "10572", "10583", "10584", "10591", "10593", "10594", "10697", 
    "11007", "11008", "11009", "11010", "11011", "11027", "11028", 
    "11029", "11030", "11040", "11068", "11215", "11359", "11469", 
    "11494", "11496", "11506", "11518", "11570", "11571", "11572", 
    "11687", "11858", "11870", "11896", "11_water", "12012", 
    "12102", "12110", "12111", "12125", "12222", "12254", "12330", 
    "12331", "12333", "12361", "12464", "12534", "12562", "12590", 
    "12602", "12604", "12605", "12618", "12621", "12648", "13025", 
    "13026", "14001", "1_land", "1_water", "20086", "20135", 
    "20169", "20170", "20190", "20196", "20198", "20199", "20231", 
    "20276", "20278", "20288", "21007", "21081", "21091", "21092", 
    "21097", "21098", "21108", "21109", "21110", "21111", "21520", 
    "21530", "22008", "22019", "2330scacou", "2_land", "2_water", 
    "3_land", "3_water", "40800", "40801", "4_land", "4_water", 
    "50138", "50162", "50183", "50217", "50218", "50229", "50304", 
    "50305", "50306", "50307", "50308", "50709", "50731", "50735", 
    "50783", "50785", "50787", "50837", "50839", "50858", "50887", 
    "50895", "50897", "50899", "50904", "50929", "50967", "51356", 
    "51357", "51361", "51365", "51801", "52003", "52127", "52171", 
    "52175", "52193", "52212", "52234", "52238", "52240", "52241", 
    "52244", "52245", "52246", "52247", "52248", "52249", "52250", 
    "52251", "52252", "52253", "52254", "52255", "52256", "52257", 
    "52258", "52259", "52260", "52261", "52262", "52263", "52264", 
    "52266", "52267", "52268", "52271", "53003", "54035", "54188", 
    "54200", "54202", "54203", "54204", "54205", "5_land", "5_water", 
    "6_land", "6_water", "70028", "70034", "70074", "70114", 
    "70122", "70156", "70158", "70175", "70215", "70251", "70278", 
    "70279", "70284", "70295", "70327", "70331", "70348", "70355", 
    "70370", "70381", "70397", "70399", "70403", "70413", "70442", 
    "70448", "70449", "70459", "70470", "70472", "70481", "70505", 
    "70519", "70525", "70529", "70550", "70552", "70556", "70563", 
    "70567", "70571", "70596", "70597", "70611", "70619", "70627", 
    "70628", "70629", "70634", "70641", "70650", "70657", "70685", 
    "70735", "71121", "71362", "71461", "71597", "71679", "71734", 
    "71811", "71887", "71917", "72008", "72021", "72092", "72093", 
    "72097", "72147", "72179", "72210", "72212", "72215", "72336", 
    "72404", "72442", "72580", "72601", "72620", "72695", "72773", 
    "72808", "72847", "72849", "72885", "72973", "72986", "72989", 
    "72996", "72998", "73037", "73042", "74060", "74061", "74269", 
    "74281", "74335", "74976", "7_land", "7_water", "82643", 
    "82644", "82645", "82646", "82682", "84218", "84221", "84226", 
    "84235", "84237", "84255", "84266", "84277", "84292", "84294", 
    "84303", "84305", "84306", "84307", "84309", "84310", "84312", 
    "84313", "84317", "84325", "84326", "84327", "84329", "84962", 
    "84963", "87495", "8_land", "8_water", "9_land", "9_water", 
    "a2w", "a3w", "a4w", "adjacent_to_sand_bar_state_park", "admin_pond", 
    "alleman", "alojamento", "altos_de_piedra", "artesia", "avilas", 
    "b10t", "b10w", "b1t", "b1w", "b2t", "b2w", "b3t", "b3w", 
    "b4t", "b4w", "b5", "b5w", "b6t", "b6w", "b7t", "b7w", "b8t", 
    "b8w", "b9t", "b9w", "beaver", "black_jack", "bp2", "bp4", 
    "bupu0039", "campana_loop", "camp_ethan_allen_pond", "camp_johnson_pond_1", 
    "camp_johnson_pond_2", "cerro_negro", "cerro_punta", "church", 
    "circle_7", "cow_pit", "cuatro_callitas", "cuchillo", "culvert_0", 
    "david's_pond", "davie's_playa", "davie's_playa__doug_burkett", 
    "deer", "doug's_office", "el_nispero", "el_valle_hotel", 
    "estrada", "farallon", "finca_el_hervidero", "fortuna_loop", 
    "gamboa", "garcia_well", "guabal", "hatchery", "horse_head_ephemeral", 
    "horse_head_permanent", "hotel_campestre", "johnson_tank", 
    "jordinal", "juan_julio", "juan_lana", "kisatchie_bayou", 
    "kurthwood", "lago_angelim_water", "lago_anta_water", "lago_minutal_water", 
    "lago_sede_water", "las_yayas", "leasburg_dam_state_park,_bridge", 
    "mata_ahogado", "medina", "miguel_de_la_borda", "natural_area_close_to_vt01_and_vt02", 
    "newt", "north_beach_pond", "olho_de_agua", "omar_torrijos", 
    "paseo_del_rio", "pena_blanca", "phelps_pond", "pine", "pirapitinga", 
    "poça_temporária_water", "rabbit_stream", "rana_dorada", 
    "range_road12", "red_tank", "red_tank_2", "rhodes_spring", 
    "rio_blanco", "rio_maria", "rio_marta", "rio_tigrero", "roadside_ditch_bude2026", 
    "rouse_tank", "rv_pond", "sargentita", "shelbourne_bay", 
    "shelbourne_pond", "sink", "solomon_lane", "sophia_stream", 
    "sora", "speamulti2237", "trilha_land", "tryon_weber", "tuttle_pond", 
    "vorisek_pond", "west", "wood_lab_pond"), list()), type = c("shiny.action", 
"", "", "", "", "", "shiny.matrix", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", ""), binding = c("shiny.actionButtonInput", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "shinyWidgets.pickerInput", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "shinyWidgets.pickerInput", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
18L)), outputs = structure(list(name = c("site_map", "cap_table"
), timestamp = c("2023-05-04 08:29:42.950-0700", "2023-05-04 08:29:36.410-0700"
), binding = c("leaflet", "datatables")), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2), 
    session = structure(list(app = "ribbitr_datarepository", 
        user = "shiny", server_connected = "2023-05-04 15:29:28.742+0000", 
        sessionid = "5f73950379b2b7a15e3999df602fe6dc", server_disconnected = "2023-05-04 15:30:06.477+0000", 
        user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36", 
        screen_res = "1920x1080", browser_res = "1708x894", pixel_ratio = 1L, 
        browser_connected = "2023-05-04 08:29:35.074-0700"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)))
```

Comment: So what is the unnested data.frame supposed to look like? How are you matching up inputs to output for a given row when the numbers don't match up. I'm not clear as to what the desired output is here. What exactly do you want to be able to do with the data after you combine it?

Comment: ultimately I would like to have some sort of data frame that maintain those variables/column names so I can filter on it. When I unlist it simply turns it into a single column data frame that does not allow me track any inputs per session or user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @MrFlick's questions are appropriate to answer first. But if you want to, for example, see which input/outputs the user interacts with over time, then you could do something like the following.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
bind_rows(data[[1]]$inputs %>%
            mutate(type = "input"),
          data[[1]]$outputs %>%
            mutate(type = "output")) %>%
  mutate(timestamp = lubridate::ydm_hms(timestamp)) %>%
  arrange(timestamp) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = timestamp,y = 0,colour = type)) +
  geom_point(aes()) +
  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(aes(label = name),max.overlaps = 20,min.segment.length = 0,force = 10000,position = position_dodge(10))
```

[image: graph showing input and output events over time]

This plot could use a lot of polishing like rearranging the repelled text. It also doesn't provide information about the value of the inputs, which are nested within the inputs data frame. Hopefully, the basic idea is clear.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to get all the data from inputs, outputs, and session into one clean data frame without nesting columns (as @Andre Wildberg did). There are some similarities between the event data in inputs and outputs that you could combine as I did. However, the session data frame contains metadata about the user/session that isn't similar to the other two objects.

Comment: This part of the code actually gets me to where I need. From there I can filter on inputs that I have of interest. ```bind_rows(data[[1]]$inputs %>%
            mutate(type = "input"),
          data[[1]]$outputs %>%
            mutate(type = "output")) %>%
  mutate(timestamp = lubridate::ydm_hms(timestamp))```

Comment: One question, you specify ```data[[1]]$inputs``` which binds the first list together. How I would I get a similiar output for all the lists. I tried ```data$inputs``` but no luck

Comment: This returns an error "no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "NULL""               ```df_format <- bind_rows(data$inputs %>%
            mutate(type = "input"),
          data$outputs %>%
            mutate(type = "output")) %>%
  mutate(timestamp = lubridate::ydm_hms(timestamp))```

Comment: For instance I have 16 lists and dont want to have to go through and do data[[2]]$inputs etc for all 16 lists. Would like to mash them all together into one df as in the format you provided with your example. Thank you for your help

Comment: If I understand how the data list is formatted, you should be able to iterate and pull out the combined inputs and outputs data frames. One solution uses the `purrr` tidyverse package as below. Note that I've added an "id" column to keep track of the iteration, but you can remove it if you'd like.
`purrr::map_dfr(data, .id = "id", ~ { bind_rows(.$inputs %>%             
                mutate(type = "input"),
              .$outputs %>%
                mutate(type = "output")) %>%
      mutate(timestamp = lubridate::ydm_hms(timestamp))  })`

Comment: That returns```Error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 3.
Caused by error in `UseMethod()`:
! no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "NULL"
Backtrace:
  1. purrr::map_dfr(...)
 11. dplyr::mutate(., type = "input")``` Does that indicate some where in my list of lists there is a list following a different structure? When I was trying different methods to create a usable df I was coming across this problem before but unsure what was causing the error.

Comment: What is the name of the list in your R environment that you'd like to iterate over? Is it called 'merged' or 'data?' You'll want to replace 'data' in the first map_dfr argument with whatever the object is called.

Answer (score 0):

A way to unfold the list is to access each element and put these in a matrix of data frames.

```
dd <- sapply(data, data.frame)

dd
                            [,1]        
inputs.name                 character,18
inputs.timestamp            character,18
inputs.value                list,18     
inputs.type                 character,18
inputs.binding              character,18
outputs.name                character,18
outputs.timestamp           character,18
outputs.binding             character,18
session.app                 character,18
session.user                character,18
session.server_connected    character,18
session.sessionid           character,18
session.server_disconnected character,18
session.user_agent          character,18
session.screen_res          character,18
session.browser_res         character,18
session.pixel_ratio         integer,18  
session.browser_connected   character,18
```

Access elements either with the index number or the row names

```
dd["session.pixel_ratio",]
$session.pixel_ratio
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```